# How can I make occur display only first line of match?

Tags: regular-expressions, search, newlines, occur

The context for this is that I was trying to write a function to help me write LaTeX, specifically I'd like to list all the future references, i.e. when you use a `\ref{<something>}` before `\label{<something>}`. I managed to write a regex that searches for this pattern, and my attempt is:

```lisp
(defun get-forward-refs ()
  "List in an occur buffer all the future references of the current file."
  (interactive)
  (occur
   (rx (regex "\\ref{") (group (+ not-newline)) "}"
       (+ anything)
       (regex "\\label{") (backref 1) "}")
   ))
```

It works, but occur annoyingly displays ALL the match, which in this case could span several lines, so that I cannot quickly navigate the list (which was the purpose of this). The docstring of occur explicitly says "If a match spreads across multiple lines, all those lines are shown.". My question is: **can I tweak this behavior, so that occur shows only the first line of the match?** Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(add-hook 'occur-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local outline-regexp "^[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+:"
                        outline-level (lambda ()
                                        1))
            (outline-minor-mode)

            ;; I believe you know how n/p works.
            (keymap-local-set "p"
                              (lambda (n)
                                (interactive "p")
                                (dotimes (_ n)
                                  (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "C-a"))
                                  (previous-error-no-select))))
            (keymap-local-set "n"
                              (lambda (n)
                                (interactive "p")
                                (dotimes (_ n)
                                  (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "C-e"))
                                  (next-error-no-select))))

            ;; To be honest, I don't know why 
            ;; `make-thread` is necessary here.
            (make-thread (lambda ()
                           (thread-yield)
                           (outline-hide-sublevels 1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! So, IIUC, `occur` by itself doesn't feature this, but you can force this behavior by using `outline-mode`? Also, like this I need two presses of `n`/`p` to navigate the results: is this a feature of `outline-mode`? Is there a way to have only one key press needed?

Comment: @AlessandroBertulli: "*is this a feature of `outline-mode`?*" -- The first `n` moves the cursor to the end of the first line, and the second one moves over the `...`. The `...` is a feature of `outline` so you should press `n` twice. ||| "*Is there a way to have only one key press needed?*" -- See my updated answer.

Comment: @AlessandroBertulli: "*`occur` by itself doesn't feature this*" -- I tried my best to find whether `occur` provides such a feature, but found nothing.

Comment: It works! Thanks you very much! Btw this is a bit over my Elisp knowledge, I'll have a look at `outline-mode`, local keymaps and threads

Comment: @AlessandroBertulli: BTW, are you sure it is correct to use `"\\ref{"`? I think you want `"\\\\ref{"`.  You might want to take a look at the elisp manual ;-)

Comment: I really don't know why, but it works for me, I don't know if I have tweaked some options and I don't remember it. But I'll investigate your suggestion about revising regexes, because right now if I have multiple reference (like `\ref{test} <...> \ref{test} <...> \label{test}`) it only lists the first one. Any suggestion about why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Without really looking into your problem, maybe this helps.

This is your regexp in Lisp, after removing the `rx` noise ;-):

```
"\\(?:\\ref{\\)\\(.+\\)}[^z-a]+\\(?:\\label{\\)\\1}"
```

`[^z-a]` matches newline chars.  I guess that corresponds to your use of `anything`.  If you don't want to match stuff over multiple lines, then you likely don't really want to match newline chars.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to match over newlines, because in my document the `\ref` and the `\label` can be several lines away